# multiple select value foreach in php

Tags: php, foreach, html-select

Ok i have the problem! :)

I have a two same name select in my page ( if statement handling ) and i forgot add value options for one.... my bad :) Thanks for replys!

---

I have a multiple selection in my page:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="diff[]">
   <option value="1">Easy</option>
   <option value="2">Medium</option>
   <option value="3">Hard</option>
</select>
```

And i want to get the option-s value so:

```
foreach($_POST['diff'] as $key) {
 echo $key;
}
```

I want to option values but i get this values ->   Easy, Medium, Hard.

How i can acces the value="" attribute ?

Thanks dudes!

Comment: You should get the value in the `value` attribute. Show us how you post your form.

Comment: Have you tried assigning names to the different options using the names="" tag in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, I guess the problem is how you post it.

Here is a little sample code, tested on my server. It gives the desierd ouput:

**Edited Code:**

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="">
    <select multiple="multiple" name="diff[]">
       <option value="1">Easy</option>
       <option value="2">Medium</option>
       <option value="3">Hard</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="button" name="mentes" id="mentes" title="Mentés az adatbázisba">Send</button>
</form>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST["diff"])) {
    foreach($_POST['diff'] as $key) {
        echo $key;
    }   
}
?>
```

When I select "easy" and press "Go" -> Output: 1

This works for all the other inputs as well.

Comment: My submit button :   <button type="submit" class="button" name="mentes" id="mentes" title="Mentés az adatbázisba">

My form :                      <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="">

I use select2 Jquery, maybe ?

Comment: Kinda sure its because of that. Because even if I replace my submit button with your code it works perfectly. Edit: Code edited.